# Convert Geospatial Points into latitude/longitude fields

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have a table with `GEOMETRY POINT` type column. I would like to add two more columns as `lat DECIMAL` and `lng DECIMAL`. 
How can this be done?

I have this table with column `loc POINT NOT NULL`.
I want sql script to update corresponding lattitude and longitude values in new added lat and lng columns.

```
old table
id    loc
1    point(18.545000, 81.782800)
2    point(20.545000, 81.782800)

updated table
id    loc                            lat         lng
1    point(18.545000, 81.782800)     18.545000   81.782800
2    point(20.545000, 81.782800)     20.545000   81.782800
```

This doesn't work

```
update table
set lat = ST_X(loc);
update table
set lng = ST_Y(loc);
```

Comment: Please share your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

This is the answer!!

```
update table
set lat = ST_Y(loc);
update table
set lng = ST_X(loc);
```